# Trouble adding an integer to an array element in shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I am trying to parse the output on svn info without resorting to an external shell command like sed or awk. This is purely academic as I know I could do this in a heartbeat with those tools.

Output I am parsing is:

```
Path: .
URL: svn://brantwinter@192.168.10.222/handbrake_batch/trunk/handbrake
Repository Root: svn://ilium007@192.168.10.222/handbrake_batch
Repository UUID: 99c2cca7-102b-e211-ab20-02060a000c0b
Revision: 6
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: ilium007
Last Changed Rev: 6
Last Changed Date: 2012-11-10 19:00:35 +1000 (Sat, 10 Nov 2012)
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -x

OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\r\n'

# Get the output from svn info into an array
SVN_INFO_ARR=(`svn info`)
COUNT=0
for i in ${SVN_INFO_ARR[@]}; do
    echo $COUNT
    echo "$i"
    (( COUNT++ ))
done

# Get the element that says "Revision: 6"
REV_ARR=${SVN_INFO_ARR[4]}

# Testing the loop over what should be a two element array
COUNT=0
for i in ${REV_ARR[@]}; do
    echo $COUNT
    echo "$i"
    (( COUNT++ ))
done

#This should give the number 6 (or string or something)
REV_NUMBER=${REV_ARR[1]}

echo ${REV_NUMBER}

### INCREMENT REVISION NUMBER FROM ARRAY ELEMENT ###

#NEW_REV_NUMBER= ????? + 1

IFS="$OLD_IFS"
```

I would like to be able to take the string:

**Revision: 6**

and pull out the 6 and increment by 1 so I can update a release txt file to be included in the SVN commit.

I have tried to make that 6 turn into a 7 for an hour now and feel like an idiot because I can't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need parenthesis: Change this:

```
# Get the element that says "Revision: 6"
REV_ARR=${SVN_INFO_ARR[4]}
```

to this:

```
# Get the element that says "Revision: 6"
REV_ARR=(${SVN_INFO_ARR[4]})
```

before

```
#This should give the number 6 (or string or something)
REV_NUMBER=${REV_ARR[1]}
```

so you'll be able to:

```
((REV_NUMBER++))
```

**Edit:**

As you wrote:

```
SVN_INFO_ARR=(`svn info`)
```

instead of just:

```
SVN_INFO_ARR=`svn info`
```

The parenthesis is used in bash to define an array. Have a look at:

```
man -Len -P'less +"/^ *Arrays"' bash
```

Comment: It was the parentheses that I was looking for - thanks @f-hauri
Can you please explain the parentheses ?

Comment: Actually it doesn't work !! Can you please explain the parentheses ?

New code:

```#!/bin/bash

set -x

OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\r\n'

# Get the output from svn info into an array
SVN_INFO_ARR=(`svn info`)

IFS="$OLD_IFS"

# Get the element that says "Revision: 6"
REV_ARR=(${SVN_INFO_ARR[4]})

#This should give the number 6 (or string or something)
REV_NUMBER=${REV_ARR[1]}
echo $REV_NUMBER
echo ((REV_NUMBER++))```

Output error:

```+ REV_ARR=(${SVN_INFO_ARR[4]})
+ REV_NUMBER=6
+ echo 6
6
./test.sh: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.sh: line 19: `echo ((REV_NUMBER++))'```

Comment: Accepted answer after being advised further down the ++ syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hardcoding the array indices, a better way would be to filter out the line you need and extract the number

Here's one way using regex (Bash 4)

```
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ Revision:\ ([0-9]+) ]]; then
         new_rev_num=$((BASH_REMATCH[1]+1))
         echo $new_rev_num
         break
    fi
done < $(svn info)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` to only select the line you need. Then, use Parameter expansion to remove "Revision: ". Finally, use `let` to do the arithmetics:

```
REVISION=$(svn info | grep '^Revision:')
REVISION=${REVISION#* }
let REVISION++
```

Comment: Thanks @choroba but I wanted to tackle this without calling an external tool such as grep but your syntax is useful and I will keep in mind for other projects.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked in the end:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

OLD_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\r\n'

# Get the output from svn info into an array
SVN_INFO_ARR=(`svn info`)

IFS="$OLD_IFS"

# Get the element that says "Revision: 6"
REV_ARR=(${SVN_INFO_ARR[4]})

#This should give the number 6 (or string or something)
REV_NUMBER=${REV_ARR[1]}
echo $REV_NUMBER
echo $(( REV_NUMBER + 1 ))
```

The answer above had me stumped for a while because it was missing the $ in front of:

```
echo $(( REV_NUMBER + 1 ))
```

and the `((REV_NUMBER++))` notation did not work, I still got 6, not 7:

```
+ OLD_IFS='     
'
+ IFS='
'
+ SVN_INFO_ARR=(`svn info`)
++ svn info
+ IFS='     
'
+ REV_ARR=(${SVN_INFO_ARR[4]})
+ REV_NUMBER=6
+ echo 6
6
+ echo 6
6
```

Comment: `((REV_NUMBER++))` only increments `REV_NUMBER` after you `echo` it, `((++REV_NUMBER))` would give you the right number.

Comment: Ok - that now makes 100% sense. Thanks.